# Laravel, Wont upload file to Public_html but instead creating folder in laravel root project

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-7, laravel-storage

im trying to upload file to public_html in server,but instead it creating new folder in laravel root project named public_html.

this is my index.php in public html

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../warkopin_management/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../warkopin_management/bootstrap/app.php';
$app->bind('path.public', function(){
    return __DIR__;
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

and this is my storage disk

```
'kategori' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('/img/kategori'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/img/kategori',
            'visibility' => 'public'],
```

this is my upload code

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            //  Let's do everything here
            if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {
                //
                $validated = $request->validate([
                    'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:10240',
                ]);
                $kategoris = new Kategoris;
                $kategoris->nama_kategori = $request->nama_kategori;
                $kategoris->kategori_induk = $request->kategori_induk;
                $kategoris->urutan = $request->urutan;
                $kategoris->visibilitas = $request->visibilitas;
                $kategoris->tampil = $request->tampil;
                $image_name = date("h:i:s").preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName());
                Storage::disk('kategori')->putFileAs('/',$request->file('image'),$image_name); 
                $kategoris->image = $image_name;
                $kategoris->save();   
                return redirect()->route('kategori.eccommerce')
                             ->with('success','kategori Berhasl Ditambahkan');
            }
        }
```

i try different method but not work. please help how to upload file to public_html file in server.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can config your filesystem like this

#### in `filesystems.php`

```php
'kategori' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => dirname(__DIR__,2).'/public_html/img/kategori',
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/img/kategori',
    'visibility' => 'public'
],
```

because `public_path()` expect `public` folder not `public_html` folder so you can use like this to work

Comment: Not working, instead it created new folder in root folder in laravel project

Comment: no need to create new folder it will upload your file into `public_html` and what folder it created ?

Comment: it create folder namen public_html in Laravel root project. so under public folder in laravel it created that folder

Comment: @BaihaqiPangestika try now and tell me what happen

Comment: still not saving the file in public_html in server

Comment: where it is save can u tell me ? so i can help you and make sure `dirname(__DIR__,1)` use this

Comment: it is save inside the Laravel directory root

Comment: @BaihaqiPangestika okay then try `'root' =>dirname(__DIR__,2).'/public_html/img/kategori',` it will go 2 level back and generate url